# bash trap '' vs trap function passing signals

Tags: bash, signals, kill, bash-trap, process-group

I'm confused about forwarding signals to child processes with traps. Say I have two scripts:

a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# print the process id
echo $$

cleanup() {
    rv=$?
    echo "cleaning up $rv"
    exit
}

sleep 5
trap '' SIGTERM # trap cleanup SIGTERM
echo 'cant stop wont stop'
./b.sh
echo 'can stop will stop'
trap - SIGTERM
sleep 4
echo 'done'
```

b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 4;
echo 'b done'
```

If I execute `a.sh` and then from another window kill the process group with `kill -- -PGID`, the SIGTERM is ignored and not passed on to `b.sh`. But if I do `trap cleanup SIGTERM`, the SIGTERM passes through and terminates `b.sh`. Why is my trap passing  the signal in one case and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting. Quoting `man 7 signal`:

> A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions.  During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default;  the  dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged.

In your case, the child always receives `TERM` by virtue of being in the same process group. The problem is, what does it do with it.

When the parent *ignores* `TERM`, by the rule above, so does the child, so the child survives. When the parent *catches* `TERM`, the child's handler will be reset, and it will die as the default action.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`trap` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=trap&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3):

> **trap [action condition ...]**
>
> *If action is null ( "" ), the shell shall ignore each specified condition if it arises.*

So when you execute `TRAP '' SIGTERM`, the `SIGTERM` condition is ignored. Try using a space value instead and see if it works:

```
sleep 5
trap ' ' SIGTERM # Note the space (' ')!!

echo 'cant stop wont stop'
./b.sh

echo 'can stop will stop'
trap - SIGTERM

sleep 4
echo 'done'
```